# How to use an HTML Include on static iis server

Tags: html, iis, static, server, include

I'm trying to build a simple HTML page with a navbar that is an include. I've been told that the server I'm building on is an iss server. Here is the html include that I'm trying to use.

```
<html>
  <body>
    <!--#include virtual="navbar.inc"-->
    <p>Content</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

I currently have index.html and navbar.inc right next to each other in the same directory.

This isn't working and I'm not sure why.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this without using the server side code. ASP, in other words

Change the extension of your index file to .asp, and try it again.

A better explanation is that HTML, being on the client (browser) side, is unaware of any files currently on the server.  ASP, on the other hand will see what you have there, and execute it, effectively including the file from the server.

Comment: or he should make changes in IIS for handle .HTML file as .ASP

Comment: or that....  I think that using the code the way it's intended is better than that workaround.  HTML is for HTML.  ASP is for ASP.  It seems odd (allowed or not) to go playing around with that.

Answer (score 0):

Read th e following article, it works.

http://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_html_include.asp